# Redirection everything to index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, indexing

I wan't to redirect everything to index.php exepept if a file or directory exists. I try'd a few ways from Google, but that really slowed the website down and don't really work so i amused that i got things wrong.

So URL like this:

```
    `site.com/Projects/S01/ -> site.com/Projects/S01/index.php (original)`
    `site.com/Projects/GE5/ -> site.com/Projects/GE5/index.php (original)`
    `site.com/Projects/     -> site.com/index.php`
    `site.com/Websites/     -> site.com/index.php`
    `sits.com/Testifcate/   -> site.com/index.php`
```

Whats the fastest way of doing this? All the methods I try'd are really slow.
Thanks you. Files such as main.css are really slow at loading also, maybe those files don't go true the check to make it faster? What the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my rewrite rule that does just that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # ensures it's not a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # ensures it's not a directory
RewriteRule . index.php [L,QSA] # . matches all, and routes to index.php if the above conditions do not match
```

Comment: (°.°) I didn't know the **`.`** could replace **`(.*)`** in **`RewriteRule . index.php [L,QSA]`**. But hey! I'm pretty sure your solution is the right one.

Comment: The parenthesis are for capturing sub-expressions, which we do not need. The `.` will match any character in the URL. So the rule matches regardless. To then retrieve the URL you could use something like `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$
RewriteRule ^$ http://domain.com/index.php [L,R=301]
```

I Hope it helps