# htaccess & php check for authorization

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have an

```
http://example.com/DL/
```

directory with free access for anyone, now I wanna to deny access for unauthorized users
so I writte very simple index.php with code

```
<?php
include('config.php');
session_start();
$result = (mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE hash='".$_SESSION['hash']."' ");
$row = mysql_fetch_array(result);
if($row['access']) {
    return true;
} else {
    header("location: /login.php");
}
?>
```

question: is there way to setup .htaccess to check if index.php returns true every time user request

```
http://example.com/DL/*
```

?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: ok, but there is no problem with sql right now, for example user request http://example.com/DL/archive.zip, and I want to check if this user authorized

Comment: The "is no problem right now" mentality will backstab you in the future. You should follow the recommendations by @PolishPrince

Comment: I did changes in my code, thanks for that! no * anymore. What about the main question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mod_rewrite to make all requests be routed to index.php.
See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161334/redirection-everything-to-index-php/8161350#8161350).

This way you can utilize the [Front Controller Pattern](http://phpmaster.com/front-controller-pattern-1/)
Which basically means that index.php will be your router into the other parts of your code. This allows for the access control that you are looking for but also lets you have a good structure of the rest of your code.

Another recommendation is to only expose index.php in your web root and have the rest of your code outside of the publicly visible folder. This way you will also prevent someone from fetching all your code base when you forget to configure apache properly.